# How can I get all occurrences of this pattern with the regex of PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

How can I get, into an array, all occurrences of this pattern 4321[5-9][7-9]{6} but excluding, for example, the occurrences where there is a digit immediately before the value, or immediately after it?

For instance, 43217999999 should be valid but **1**43217999999 (note the number **1** at the beginning) should not be valid.

As the first example, 43217999999**1** shouldn't be valid because of the **1** that it has in the end.

The added difficulty, at least for me, is that I have to parse this in whatever position I can find it inside a string.

The string looks like this, literally:

43217999997 / **5**43217999999 // 43217999998 _ 43217999999a43216999999-43216999999 arandomword 43215999999**7**

As you would be able to note, it has no standard way of separating the values (I marked in bold the values that would make it invalid, so I shouldn't match those)

My idea right now is something like this:

```
(\D+|^)(4321[5-9][7-9]{6})(\D+|$)
```

(\D+|^) meaning that I expect in that position the start of the string or at least one non-digit and (\D+|$) meaning that I expect there the end of the string or at least one non-digit.

That obviously doesn't do what I picture in my head.

I also tried do it in two steps, first:

```
preg_match_all("/\D+4321[5-9][7-9]{6}\D+|4321[5-9][7-9]{6}\D+|4321[5-9][7-9]{6}$/", $input, $outputArray);
```

and then:

```
for($cont = 0; $cont < count($outputArray); $cont++) {
   preg_match("/4321[5-9][7-9]{6}/", $outputArray[0][$cont], $outputArray2[]);
}
```

so I can print

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($outputArray2, true) . "</pre>";
```

but that doesn't let me exclude the ones that have a number before the start of the value (**5**432157999999 for example), and then, I am not making any progress with my idea.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use word boundaries  `\b4321[5-9][7-9]{6}\b`

Comment: @revo, thank you for your suggestion. The problem with using word boundaries is that, as far as I know, it allows you to parse something that is separated with space or space-like characters (am I right?). In this case, the characters that separate the value are sometimes letters, sometimes special chars, just sometimes spaces or space-like chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you literally want to check if there is no digit before or after the match you can use negative look ahead and look behind.

- `(?![0-9])` at the end means: "is not followed by 0-9"
- `(?<![0-9])` at the start means: "is not preceded by 0-9"

See this example https://regex101.com/r/6xbmJk/1

Comment: Thank you! That does exactly what I need. I don't know if I should open another question for this, but, do you think this problem should be solved with another approach?